# Edge extension says "Wants access to this site", and has red background

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

My Edge extension's manifest.json contains the following sections:

```json
{
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "exclude_matches": ["http://*.highpin.cn/ResumeManage/ResumeList*"],
      "js": [
        "libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js",
        "libs/pako/pako.min.js",
        "js/shared/config.js",
        "js/content/content_loader.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

This happens in some Edge browsers. Only users can click it to use it.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there the same behavior in Chrome? If possible, please provide a minimal code example so we can reproduce this issue, thanks for understanding.